# Remote validation for kendowindow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I implement remote validation. It works for usual fields correctly, but if field is situated in kendowindow jquery validation does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VladimirIliev No. I wrote own attribute

Comment: Could you please share it in current thread? This might be helpful for the other users.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using Kendo UI validator as demonstrated below:

**Model with "Remote" annotation attribute:**

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("UniqueName", "Home", ErrorMessage = "The entered name already exists.")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller with "UniqueName" Action:**

```
public ActionResult UniqueName(string productName)
{
    var context = new NorthwindEntities();

    return Json(!context.Products.Any(p => p.ProductName == productName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Script to add custom validation rule to the Kendo UI validation rules for the "Remote" validation attribute (can be placed anywhere on the page before Grid initialization code):**

```
<script>
    (function ($, kendo) {
        $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
            rules: {
                //define custom validation rule to match remote validation:
                mvcremotevalidation: function (input) {
                    if (input.is("[data-val-remote]") && input.val() != "") {
                        var remoteURL = input.attr("data-val-remote-url");
                        var valid;

                        $.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            url: remoteURL,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: validationData(input, this.element),
                            success: function (result) {
                                valid = result;
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                valid = false;
                            }
                        });

                        return valid;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            },
            messages: {
                mvcremotevalidation: function (input) {
                    return input.attr("data-val-remote");
                }
            }
        });

        function validationData(input, context) {
            var fields = input.attr("data-val-remote-additionalFields").split(",");
            var name = input.prop("name");
            var prefix = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            var fieldName;
            var data = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                fieldName = fields[i].replace("*.", prefix);
                data[fieldName] = $("[name='" + fieldName + "']", context).val();
            }
            return data;
        }
    })(jQuery, kendo);

</script>
```

**Grid initialization code:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMVC5.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Command(comm =>
        {
            comm.Edit();
        });
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
            })
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home"))
    )
)
```